# Can't create fields of type Time on shapefile layers

Tags: qgis, python, vector-layer, datetime

I wanted to create new field in QGIS to store date and time from a datetime string field named dateposte. Here is the code I used to make it:

```
import datetime  
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
for layer_id, layer in layers.items():
    #creating new field
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("date", QVariant.Date) ] )
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("time", QVariant.Time) ] )
    layer.updateFields()
    with edit(layer):
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            thedatetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(feature['dateposte'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('date'), thedatetime.date())
            feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('time'), thedatetime.time())
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

But I got error on this line:

```
feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('time'), thedatetime.time())
```

and getting error message

```
Erreur OGR lors la création du champ time : Can't create fields of type Time on shapefile layers.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The dBase format (.dbf) that is used in shapefile for attributes does support only date, not time. Use some other format like GeoPackage, or store your times as strings.

Comment: Don't use a shapefile - move to GeoPackages which don't suffer from this problem

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to [How To: Create a time animation from a shapefile](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012836):

> To create a time animation, Date/Time data is required. The Date type
> fields **in a shapefile support either the date or the time, but not
> both in the same field.**
>
> Sometimes, a problem arises when exporting a geodatabase feature class
> containing a Date/Time field to a shapefile. After exporting, the time
> value in the shapefile is truncated. Only the date value is
> maintained.
>
> Shapefiles containing date and time data in a String type field can
> still be used to create a time animation to visualize temporal data
> over time.